# Word Usage for "regret"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Can someone please give me one word for ***regretting after saying something***?

For example, suppose I say something to somebody and then I regret saying that and think why did I even open my mouth.

So what will be one word for *regret saying that*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms *[chagrin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chagrin#Noun)* (“Distress of mind caused by a failure of aims or plans, want of appreciation, mistakes etc; vexation or mortification”) and
 *[mortification](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mortification#Noun)* (“A sensation of extreme shame or embarrassment”) are relevant here, although they may apply to regret for actions as well as words, and are nouns rather than verbs.  (As for verbs, one sometimes hears expressions like  “I'm kicking myself for saying that”.)

Answer (score 1):

There are exclamations to express that regret, such as **[whoops](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whoops)** or **[oops](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oops?show=0&t=1383322669)**.

> to say in a mild way that you are sorry about having done or said something wrong

You also could say *I should have **[bit my tongue](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bite%20your%20tongue)***.